# JAX-WS Monitor WebMethod usage and performance

Tags: java, web-services, monitoring

I am building a WebService with token-based auth, token is extracted from soap headers. I want to monitor/profile every WebMethod, I want to know which user called which WebMethod and how long it took to process it. I cannot use external monitoring tools because I still need to extract the token, so I know which user actually called that WebMethod.

I am now using a simple class WebFilter that is called before every WebMethod manually and throws exception if user does not have permissions to call that method. But adding something like `long start = System.currentMillis();` before every method and after calculating the time is not a solution as I will have hundrends of methods.

```
@WebService (serviceName = "UserService")
public class UserService implements IUserService {

@Resource
WebServiceContext wsctx;

@WebMethod
@Override
public User getUser(@WebParam(name = "name") String name) throws ServiceException {
    WebFilter.filter(wsctx.getMessageContext());
    return userManager.getUser(name);
}
```

I am looking for something like Interceptors solution, I need to call something before every WebMethod and after it, but Interceptors do not really work with WebMethods so I am kinda desperate about it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with annotation before every monitored class:

```
@Interceptors({PerformanceInterceptor.class})
```

And this Interceptor implmentation:

```
@AroundInvoke
public Object methodInterceptor(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
   long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
   try {
       return ctx.proceed();
   } finally {
       long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
       System.out.println(ctx.getMethod().getName() + " took: " + (end - start) + "ms");
   }
}
```